# Shortcut (programmatically) open a link in a new tab without focus to that tab

Tags: google-chrome

Google search + Google Chrome browser have this implemented, when you browse the google search results using your up and down arrows (only possible in Chrome browser) and than press CTRL+ENTER it opens the search result selected in a new tab but without focus to that tab. You can now use up and down keys in the same list of search results and CTRL-ENTER more results in new tabs to visit later on.

Does anyone have any idea how this is done? As it only works with Google Chrome at the moment I suspect something is added to the browser as well but I can't find anything on this subject.

Comment: Ctrl-clicking a link does the same thing, does it not?

Comment: yes. But i want to bind it to a shortcut and open the link in a new tab without focus using a shortcut.

Comment: You mean programmatically? Or you just want a hotkey (other than ctrl-click) to do it for you? If the latter, you might get better help on Super User or http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I mean programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I have seen this done before is for the webpage to listen for key presses (e.g., j/k) and simply focus() the desired link. Then, when the user presses Enter or Ctrl-Enter, he is simply performing the default operation on the focused link.

Sure enough, when I type this into the javascript console on a Google search result page, I see the links that are being focused.

```
document.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {console.log(e.target)}, true);
```

So Google is still using the same technique, although it's not so obvious because they hide the dotted outline around the focused link using CSS (`a.noline{outline:0}`).

Comment: This is indeed the same used as the solution. Set the focus of the right link when you hover or navigate there. The effect of this is the same as if you tabbed to that particular link making it active, such that the browser command renders it in the background.